# "expires_date" in an in-app purchase receipt is set to earlier date than "purchase_date" in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, storekit

I am currently testing my in-app subscription purchase in the sandbox mode. If you have ever done this, I sympathize with you.

I am getting a very weird Apple Receipt back when I try to validate my purchase. Somehow the `expires_date` on my purchase is earlier in time compared to the `purchase_date`. This obviously cannot be, a subscription cannot expire before it was bought... I am just wondering if anyone has ever experienced this. Im hoping it's some funky apple sandbox bug.

If during the subscription period i restart the application and request the receipt, I get the correct one with incrementing subscriptions. Once I put the application in background and bring back to foreground, request receipt, I get a totally different receipt with erroneous `expires_date`.

Here is the good receipt I get after two subscription renewals, I had to restart the app to get this...

`"latest_receipt_info" =     (
                {
            "expires_date" = "2014-07-16 20:57:28 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1405544248000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 13:57:28 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2014-07-16 20:54:29 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1405544069000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 13:54:29 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000117061189;
            "product_id" = "com.test.subscription";
            "purchase_date" = "2014-07-16 20:57:40 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1405544260063;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 13:57:40 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000117061189;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000028408117;
        },
                {
            "expires_date" = "2014-07-16 21:00:28 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1405544428000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 14:00:28 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2014-07-16 20:56:35 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1405544195000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 13:56:35 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000117061189;
            "product_id" = "com.test.subscription";
            "purchase_date" = "2014-07-16 20:57:40 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1405544260063;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 13:57:40 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000117061258;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000028408116;
        }
    );
    receipt =     {
        "adam_id" = 0;
        "application_version" = "1.99.9";
        "bundle_id" = "com.test.company";
        "download_id" = 0;
        "in_app" =         (
                        {
                "expires_date" = "2014-07-16 20:57:28 Etc/GMT";
                "expires_date_ms" = 1405544248000;
                "expires_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 13:57:28 America/Los_Angeles";
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2014-07-16 20:54:29 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1405544069000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 13:54:29 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000117061189;
                "product_id" = "com.test.subscription";
                "purchase_date" = "2014-07-16 20:54:33 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1405544073000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 13:54:33 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000117061189;
                "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000028408117;
            }
        );
        "original_application_version" = "1.0";
        "original_purchase_date" = "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT";
        "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1375340400000;
        "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";
        "receipt_type" = ProductionSandbox;
        "request_date" = "2014-07-16 20:57:40 Etc/GMT";
        "request_date_ms" = 1405544260075;
        "request_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 13:57:40 America/Los_Angeles";
    };
    status = 0;
}`

and here is the bad receipt I start getting when I put the app in BG and then FG...

`"latest_receipt_info" =     (
                {
            "expires_date" = "2014-07-15 19:44:07 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1405453447000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2014-07-15 12:44:07 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2014-07-15 19:41:08 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1405453268000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-07-15 12:41:08 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000116920864;
            "product_id" = "com.test.subscription";
            "purchase_date" = "2014-07-16 21:23:55 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1405545835331;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-07-16 14:23:55 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000116920864;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000028402326;
        }`

as you can see the `purchase_date`is actually in the future if you compare it to the `expires_date`... what is this whichery?!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Note timezones.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst at the time of purchase of any IAP, the purchase_date will show just that, afterwards it will show the date / time or the restoration of the receipt.

If you wish to get the actual purchase date, use the original_purchase_date field. If you look in the receipts you are showing, you will see this then looks correct.

In short, you must use the original_purchase_date field to get the time/date of the actual original transaction.